# Change site looks based on loggedin users profile property

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page

Which is best practice to achieve change in look (color of top bar) based on a custom user profile property?

Property has value yes/no/null.

1. Using pre init event to change masterpage dynamically? I am worried this technique will update show last updated master page if property is null.
2. Loading the css file dynamically via user control.
3. Any other method?

Comment: If it's only about changing the top suite bar color and assuming you're using on-prem, I would suggest using a Delegate Control and load it into AdditionalPageHead.

Comment: I was planning to use user control and apply the change theme based on property

Comment: If that's the case, the last logged in user will be overriding the theme. On each page refresh, theme will get updated.

Comment: Yes so current user will always get to see his theme because thats coded to check via user control in masterpage...

Comment: You'd be constantly updating the web w/ theme for every refresh for every user that falls within those N groups

Comment: Finally each user will get to see his theme as it is the updated one and specific to that user

Comment: I thought you were looking for the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You have below options:

- OPTION 1:

Use a custom user control where you get the UPS property & based on the value register a script using

> ScriptManager.RegisterStartUp

or some other way based on whether you are using Update panels in your control.

Basically you have to do below in the script file/function:
using JQuery get the top bar HTML element & set the css using

> $(".classNameofTopBar").css({background-color: Red});

Alternatively you can add a CSS reference from your code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943037/adding-stylesheets-programmatically-in-asp-net

You must finally ensure that you have CACHING enabled for your user control as it will fire every time. You need to consider performance too and I believe the UPS property wont change that frequently.

- OPTION 2:

See whether the UPS property is exposed to the OOB SharePoint property loader control. In SP 2010 we can just add a reference to OOB user control & then use it in your JS code to set the color as stated above.

http://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/user-information-in-sharepoint-2010-with-help-of-the-spcwc-control/

Comment: Is it possible to apply new css aftr page is loaded?

Comment: Yes using JQuery its easy. Try this link : http://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/dynamically-loading-css-and-js-files-using-jquery/